# Error: 'jQuery is not defined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have written a script with jQuery.
It works with Firefox and GoogleChrome.
Only with IE I have this error returned:

> 'jQuery' is not defined  jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js, Row 10 Character 1

This is the head of my page:

```
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Contattaci - TheItalianBrand.com</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="lib/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <script type="application/javascript">
       $(function(){



    $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
     function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
     function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
    );

    $('input').change(function() {
      validate();
    });
    $('input').keydown(function() {
      validate();
    });
    $('textarea').change(function() {
      validate();
    });
    $('textarea').keydown(function() {
      validate();
    });
   });
   </script>
   </head>
```

What can I do?

Comment: You... did not close that last `script` tag

Comment: Don't use the `application/javascript` MIME type; IE will choke on that. Use `text/javascript` instead.

Comment: sorry the last <script tag is closed but i don't paste it

Comment: @Marcel. I'd have posted that as an answer! :-)

Comment: @James: yeah, but I don't think it's *the* answer. The script section is simply ignored by IE, but the error seems to occur somewhere else.

Comment: If you enter ...lib/jquery.js into IE's address bar, does it look right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use `application/javascript`, change to `text/javascript`
2. Check the path of jquery
   is your jquery in `lib/js/`, or just `lib/`?
3. Make sure your lib directory is relative to the calling page
   You may have meant `/lib/jquery.js` (the slash in the beginning makes a difference)

Answer (score 2):

You're importing the jQuery UI library from `lib/js`, but jQuery itself from `lib`.  I suspect that your copy of the jQuery library is also in `lib/js` and that you're just not getting it due to that incorrect path. Of course, that would mean that it's not actually working in Firefox or Chrome or any other browser, but it could be that they're just less strident about error reporting so you're not noticing.

The Firefox "TamperData" plugin is really handy for tracking HTTP requests on page loads.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check sequence of added jQuery, and adding jQuery library in proper sequence