# jQuery undefined on iframe loaded on IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a page in HTML with a little function using jQuery and JavaScript (code is not relevant) debugging my app on chrome and firefox it's ok. When I debug on IE I get jQuery is undefined error message. I solved this adding this line to my HTML code:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

With this now my page works fine on Firefox, Chrome and IE. My problem is that I'm trying to display this page on an **iframe** and works fine on Firefox and Chrome but again is not working on IE. Searching for a solution I find that adding **X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge** on HTTP response headers on IIS solves the problem but affects functionality of my main web page so I think that this solution is not possible.

**EDIT: Code added**

```
<script src="../js/core/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/core/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/core/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.countdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#clock').countdown('2019/08/11 19:00:00', function (event) {
            var days = event.strftime('%D');
            var hr= event.strftime('%H');
            var mn = event.strftime('%M');
            var sc = event.strftime('%S');

            $('#clock').html(days);
            $('#clock2').html(hr);
            $('#clock3').html(mn);
            $('#clock4').html(sc);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Are you using application/javascript while including your script tag? If yes than try to use text/javascript and again try to test the code. If possible than try to post your sample code. We will try to make a test with IE to see the results at our end. It may help to narrow down the issue. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590711/error-jquery-is-not-defined

Comment: What version of IE? What version of jQuery? Do you get any errors *before* the jQuery is undefined one? Does it really say jQuery is undefined or is it $?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I tried with bot and same result. I also added my code but like I said is not very helpful. That code and page works fine individually. I have my main page and I'm trying to add an iframe with this page and code and thats the point when I'm getting this error.

Comment: @Quentin IE11, Jquery v3.2.1 and I'm getting the following error on that sequence. Expected identifier (popper.min.js(4,5682)), Expected identifier bootstrap.min.js, Object doesnt support property or method addEventListener jQuery, jQuery is undefined, the value of the property $ is null or undefined countdown.js

Answer (score 0):

I test your code and it runs well on my side. I use online path of jQuery and countdown and it shows no error. Check if the path of jQuery is correct.
If I use compatibility view or enterprise mode, I'll get jQuery is undefined error. Check if compatibility view or enterprise mode is disabled. You can also refer to [the accepted answer of this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178845/ie11-jquery-error)

[image]

[image]